# The static field should be accessed in a static way

Tags: java, static, enums

I have different Exception category Enum as below

```
public enum GSBBCacheCategory  {
    SEARCH(9001),
    UPDATE_PERSECURITY(9002),
    CROSS_REFERENCING_PERSECURITY(9003),
    METADATA_SEARCH(9004),
    REMOVEALL(9005),
    UPDATE_BACKOFFICE(9002);

    private int exceptionCode;

    GSBBCacheCategory(int exceptionCode)
    {
        this.exceptionCode = exceptionCode;
    }

    public int getExceptionCode()
    {
        return exceptionCode;
    }
} 

public enum GSBBEncryptionCategory  {
.
.
.
}
```

I want to provide one place to access these Enum in client code.  Presently I achieved this as below

```
public class GSBBExceptionCodes
{
 public static GSBBDecryptionCategory decryptionCategory;
 public static GSBBCacheCategory cacheCategory;
}
```

Now to access exception code I have do something like below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println(GSBBExceptionCodes.decryptionCategory.ERRORCODE_DECRYPTION_FAILURE);
     System.out.println(GSBBExceptionCodes.cacheCategory.UPDATE_PERSECURITY);
}
```

Which says “**The static field GSBBDecryptionCategory.ERRORCODE_DECRYPTION_FAILURE should be accessed in a static way**”

Is it possible to achieve above without any warning?

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways to reference a static member (either a field or a method). One is `WhateverClass.theField`, and the other is `someInstance.theField` where `someInstance` has a compile-time type of `WhateverClass`. The former is much clearer, and so your IDE is helpfully telling you to use it instead of the latter.

The reason it's better is that referencing a static member by an instance makes it look like the method has something to do with that instance, which it doesn't. Here's a real-life example:

```
Thread myThread = getMyThread();
myThread.start();
myThread.sleep(5000);
```

At first blush, it looks like you're asking `myThread` to sleep for 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds), but that's not what you're doing at all. You're asking the *current* thread to sleep, because that last line is exactly the same as invoking `Thread.sleep(5000)`. That second example is much more clearly a static method.

Or, here's another example. Let's say your static fields were mutable.

```
public class Foo {
    public static int value = 1;
}
```

(This public static mutable field is a bad idea for other reasons, but simplifies the example). Now let's say you do:

```
Foo one = new Foo();
Foo two = new Foo();
one.value = 2;
two.value = 3;
System.out.println(one.value);
System.out.println(two.value);
```

Kinda looks like that should print "2" and then "3", right? But no -- it'll print "3", "3" because both assignments to `.value` are in fact to the same, static field. It's just an optical illusion that the `one` or `two` instances have anything to do with anything.

Imho, the ability to reference static members from instances is a misfeature. But it's there, so you should avoid it. Which is what the compiler is trying to suggest you do.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println(GSBBDecryptionCategory.ERRORCODE_DECRYPTION_FAILURE);
     System.out.println(GSBBCacheCategory.UPDATE_PERSECURITY);
}
```

You are now accessing the field in a static way which should remove the warning.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like instead of having these as `public static` fields, they should be inner classes:

```
public class GSBBExceptionCodes {
  public enum GSBBCacheCategory {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: yes this is good solution but the problem with this is that I have to define all category in one class, I have near about 20 category and each have 5 constant which is not good to have in one class.

Comment: If you want to "provide one place to access these Enum in client code," this is how you have to do it.  Personally, I'd go for @Simon's approach and abandon the hope of merging these into one place.